# Borrow mut element from a mut reference of a vec?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm having this issue in one of my projects, that I've managed to reproduce in the playground:

```
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub vec: Option<&'a mut Vec<u8>>,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn some_borrow(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<&mut u8> {
        match &self.vec {
            None => println!("nope"),
            Some(vec) => match vec.get_mut(index) {
                None => println!("no elements"),
                Some(int) => return Some(int),
            }
        }
        return None;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 2];
    let mut data = MyStruct{ vec: Some(&mut vec) };
    
    data.some_borrow(1);
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `**vec` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:32
  |
9 |             Some(vec) => match vec.get_mut(index) {
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `vec` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

I don't quite understand: if the vec is borrowed, why can't I borrow an element from it?

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c40afdc6a6cc0acc4024f27f07995c38)

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/VirgileHenry/Foundry) (building the project will directly lead to the error itself, it works well otherwise).

Comment: Note that if you don't need the `println!` calls, you can make this method a lot more terse. You can replace the entire body with `self.vec.as_mut()?.get_mut(index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.vec` is borrowed immutably (`match &self.vec`), but you want to change it (`get_mut()`) so you need to borrow it mutably:

```rust
match &mut self.vec {
    None => println!("nope"),
    Some(vec) => match vec.get_mut(index) {
        None => println!("no elements"),
        Some(int) => return Some(int),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Vec::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get_mut) requires to be applied on a `&mut self` (see the signature of the function).

That means you need to have a *mutable reference* to an `Vec` instance in order to call that method.

In your:

```rust
match &self.vec { // <----- here you are taking a &self.vec
    None => ..
    Some(vec) => ..
}
```

You are taking a reference (*immutable*)  to the variable member `vec` of your struct.

That implies the result of that expression gives you "read-only" access to that vector object (and thus you cannot invoke a method that mutates the state of the vector).

Therefore:

---

#### Solution 1

Taking a `&mut self.vec` as matching expression:

```rust
match &mut self.vec {
    None => ..
    Some(vec) => ...
}
```

[Playground live](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d88e307d66de2dec9f80fa3f09602ed)

---

#### Solution 2

Since `self.vec` is an `Option`, there is a convenient method for those scenarios.

[`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut).

```rust
match self.vec.as_mut() {
  None => ..
  Some(vec) => ..
}
```

[Playground live](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba1671a93ce924cb212f8b2fa8f1bbd1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I'm still getting lifetimes errors in my peject, so I guess I didn't quite managed to replicate my error.